# AJAX POST vs GET

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, post, razor-pages

I'm wondering if it really makes any difference if I use GET or POST in my AJAX calls.

I'm using AJAX to delete an item with a specified ID. Somehow, POST seemed like it was a more fitting choice. But with Razor Pages, an AJAX POST requires several steps to work around [cross site request forgery measures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1#javascript-ajax-and-spas).

Does it make any difference if I just GET or POST here? Or are there any anti patterns I'm hitting if I don't?

Answer (score 2):

There are many perspectives from which to answer your question "Does it make any difference if I just GET or POST here?"  **In short, YES it makes a difference.**

GET and POST are both susceptible to CSRF attacks. By using a GET you are creating a wider attack surface.  For example an IMG tag in an email could run your DELETE api on an unsuspecting user.  Using a POST makes it less trivial.  You'd be better off using post without supporting anti-forgery than by using GET. Ideally, you're using POST with anti-forgery tokens.

Other considerations can include:

- How the cache handles this request
- Adherence to REST principles (assuming you intend to have a "REST"ful/like design)
- It's usually assumed that a get doesn't directly manipulate server side state
- In theory a URL identifies the location of a resource, if you delete that resource with a get, what happens next time you call the get?
- A get won't be protected by CORS because it's assumed to not modify state, the browser will execute the GET and just not return the response to the offending site.  With a POST the browser will run a CORS preflight check using the OPTIONS verb to make sure the request is allowed by the CORS policy returned by your server prior to your server receiving a request with the verb POST.

Comment: While I agree with this answer, REST is only a set of ideas/ guidelines. Assuming you want REST sometimes you have to bend the scope. eg a "Get" call with sensitive information should not be made in a Get request.

Comment: Well, this is a Razor Page and not an API. But it sounds like you recommend GET only be used when no data will be modified.

Comment: For sure. REST is a set of ideas you have to "subscribe" to when designing an API. There is no single right way to do anything.  When it comes to modifying state with a GET vs a POST there are a lot of reasons to not modify state with a GET.

Comment: The guidance for not sending sensitive information on a GET is mostly to do with logging.  Logging can be leaky no matter which verb is used.  The data on your GET receives the same level of protection as data in a POST body.

Comment: @MarkAtRamp51: I'm not sure if that last comment was an answer to me. But, apparently, Razor Pages implement CSRF protection for POST but not GET.

Comment: @JonathanWood no it was response to Austin.  That comment is in regards to the protection of data, it's not related to CSRF.  CSRF is really protection from bad actors performing unauthorized/unwanted actions on behalf of another.